# Formatting year in PHP from SQL database using date()?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have upload dates for images stored in a MySQL database as type 'datetime'.

e.g. 2013-04-16 00:20:00

But no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the date to echo correctly in my PHP code. This is what I currently have:

```
$session_query = mysql_query($sql);
$upload_date_formatted = date('M jS, Y', $session_query['upload_date']);
echo '<h6> Uploaded on '.$upload_date_formatted.' .</h6>';
```

Using the example above, this always gives: 'Uploaded on Jan 1st, 1970.'.

Any ideas? I've tried loads of things, but I just can't seem to get this date to display correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

---

You need to call [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysql-fetch-assoc) on `$session_query` to convert it to a usable array.

You will also need to pass `$session_query['upload_date']` through [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert it to the integer that `date()` is expecting.

```
$session_query = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($session_query);
$upload_date_formatted = date('M jS, Y', strtotime($row['upload_date']));
echo '<h6> Uploaded on '.$upload_date_formatted.' .</h6>';
```

As it is you are attempting to pass an array key from a non-array, which will be `null`, which when cast to an integer by `date()` will be zero, resulting in the 01/01/1970 date you are seeing. This will also raise a couple of errors - you should turn on error reporting as it will help you track down errors in the development environment much more quickly:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

---

Alternatively you can use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, and the [`createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat) method:

```
$session_query = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($session_query);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['upload_date']);
$upload_date_formatted = $date->format('M jS, Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to a Unix timestamp first using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), then you can format it using `date()`.

```
$session_query = mysql_query($sql);
$upload_date_formatted = date( 'M jS, Y', strtotime( $session_query['upload_date'] ) );
echo '<h6> Uploaded on '.$upload_date_formatted.' .</h6>';
```

*As a side note, the* [mysql_](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799)* *extensions have been deprecated. Try [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.*

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL [Date_Format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function instead of [PHP](http://www.php.net) with the format as '%b %e, %Y'